# Installing Soundnode in elementary os loki

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install Soundnode (a soundcloud client for linux). I ran the following in terminal as directed in their website.

> curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/JonasGroeger/soundnode/script.deb.sh | sudo bash

But when i do so i get the following error

> Unable to download repo config from: https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/JonasGroeger/soundnode/config_file.list?os=elementary&dist=loki&source=script
>
> This usually happens if your operating system is not supported by
> packagecloud.io, or this script's OS detection failed.

I am a linux newbie and don't know what all that means.

Can you help me here? If a solution to the above problem is not obvious, then there is a linux 64 bit zip file available at their site http://www.soundnodeapp.com. Can you tell me how to install from this if above method is not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common issue where application installation scripts don't support Ubuntu based distro's like elementary OS. Like the error mentions:

> This usually happens if your operating system is not supported by 
>   packagecloud.io, or this script's OS detection failed.
>
> You can override the OS detection by setting os= and dist= prior to running this script.
>   You can find a list of supported OSes and distributions on our website: https://packagecloud.io/docs#os_distro_version
>
> For example, to force Ubuntu Trusty: os=ubuntu dist=trusty ./script.sh

There is already an issue opened: https://github.com/Soundnode/soundnode-app/issues/1008
It contains the following workaround:

```
curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/JonasGroeger/soundnode/script.deb.sh | sudo os=ubuntu dist=xenial bash
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install soundnode
```

(Tip in general: check the application's issue queue)

Hopefully they will provide a Snap / Flatpack / AppImage. Then you wouldn't have this issue. Also see: 
https://github.com/Soundnode/soundnode-app/issues/984